# Angular 1/ ng-if one-time binding only in a condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select, angular-ui-select, angularjs-ng-if

In my template i have :

```
<div ng-if="$ctrl.show()">
  <input class="form-control" type="text">
</div>
```

In my component

```
  show() {
    if (angular.isDefined(this.parking.parkingType)) {
      return this.parking.parkingType.labelKey === 'parking_type.air'
    }
  }
```

I want angular to process the function only when clicking on a select input (ui-select) by the attribute `on-select="$ctrl.show()"` :

```
 <ui-select ng-model="$ctrl.parking.parkingType"
             on-select="$ctrl.show()">
    <ui-select-match allow-clear="true">
        <span>{{ $select.selected.label }}</span>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in $ctrl.parkingType | filter: { label: $select.search }">
        <span ng-bind-html="item.label"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

This case may be similar to a sample case of: launching the function only when clicking on an `ng-click`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your ng-show to a variable and keep `on-select="$ctrl.show()"` as is

In your view:

```
<div ng-if="$ctrl.shouldShow">
  <input class="form-control" type="text">
</div>
```

In your component:

```
$ctrl.show = function() {
  if (angular.isDefined(this.parking.parkingType)) {
    $ctrl.shouldShow = (this.parking.parkingType.labelKey === 'parking_type.air')
  }
}
```

It's a good practice not to have a function in ng-if, ng-show, and ng-hide because it's a performance hit

Comment: Angular does not evaluate constantly the variables `$ctrl.shouldShow` ?

Comment: sorry, during the digest cycles it will, but evaluating a function obviously will take more time than a boolean, and setting it to a boolean gives you the functionality you need

Comment: So if I understand, it comes down to the same, Angular goes all the time looking for `$ctrl.shouldShow` if exist or not.
What exactly is the difference?

Comment: it would help you to read up on the angularjs digest cycle to further understand the difference.